# Checking the value of radio button submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, form-submit

I'm trying to validate the value found the in the radio button when the submit button is clicked.  I'm not sure of the proper syntax, this is what I've pieced together from what I've found online so far.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('testing');

// Create array to traverse so that on clicking submit, the current question
//is deleted, and the next question in the array is loaded.  
var questionsArray = [];

//Create counters for both correct answers and current question
var correctAnswers = 0;
var currentQuestion = 0;

//String to use for messages
var rightAnswer = "That's correct!  You have " + correctAnswers + " out of 10 correct!";
var wrongAnswer = "Oh dear, that's so so wrong! You have " + correctAnswers + " out of 10 correct";

//Contructor Function to create questions
function Question (question, choices, answer){
    this.question = question;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
}

//Question Creations
questionsArray.push(new Question('Who is the Flash', ['Walter White', 'Johnny Cage', 'Barry Allen', 'Peter Parker'], 'Barry Allen'));

//Testing:

$('.q_question').append(questionsArray[0]['question']);
$('.btn1').after(questionsArray[0]['choices'][0]);
$('.btn2').after(questionsArray[0]['choices'][1]);
$('.btn3').after(questionsArray[0]['choices'][2]);
$('.btn4').after(questionsArray[0]['choices'][3]);

$('#submit').on('click', function(){
    alert('click!');   //Test to make sure the click on submit is being recorded.
    currentQuestion ++;
    var answer = $('input[name="1"]:checked').val();  //The .val() is new to me, pretty sure this is where I've gone wrong
    if(answer == questionsArray[0]['answer']){
        correctAnswers ++;
        $('.jumbotron').append(rightAnswer);
    } else {
        $('.jumbotron').append(wrongAnswer);
    }
});


});
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/css.css'>
  <title>Super Awesome Quiz!</title>
 </head>
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <h1 classs = "title">Welcome to My Super Awesome Quiz!!</h1>
    <h3 class="question_counter">Ver. 1.1</h3>
  </header>


  <form class = "question">
    <h2 class= "q_title"> </h2>   <!-- Will use questionCounter here once created -->
    <h3 class="q_question"></h3>

      <input class='btn btn1' type="radio" name="1" value="answer" >
        <br>
      <input class='btn btn2' type="radio" name="1" value="answer" >
        <br>
      <input class='btn btn3' type="radio" name='1' value='answer' >
        <br>
      <input class='btn btn4' type="radio" name='1' value='answer' >
        <br>
      <input id="submit" type='submit' name='1' value='Submit'>
        <br>
  </form>
  <div class='jumbotron'>
    <h2></h2>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: And what does the HTML look like ?

Comment: The `value` for all your radio buttons is `answer`, and comparing `answer` to `Barry Allen` is false (`"Barry Allen" === "answer"` <- false ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you're not updating the value of the radio input:

```
$('.q_question').append(questionsArray[0]['question']);
$('.btn1').after(questionsArray[0]['choices'][0]);
$('.btn1').val(questionsArray[0]['choices'][0]); // set value to option value
...
```

This will cause the value of the input to hold the actual value which can be compared to the correct answer.

Another option is to compare to the value of the text after the radio button.

Comment: Thanks! That got it.  Unfortunately the text I append to the document only flashes on the screen for a split second. Is there a way to get it to stay permanently printed to the screen?

Comment: What text is flashing?

Comment: Dependent upon the answer, it's one of these two values:                            var rightAnswer = "That's correct!  You have " + correctAnswers + " out of 10 correct!";
var wrongAnswer = "Oh dear, that's so so wrong! You have " + correctAnswers + " out of 10 correct";

Comment: Your form is being submitted and you are not preventing the default of the page reloading after submit.add return false to the end of your submit function to only handle the form submission in javascript.

Comment: Added a jsFiddle of your code.. yiu'd be better off next time creating one yourelf.. helps to understand the code https://jsfiddle.net/5r9u39mx/

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm a super noob (which is obvious).  I've been using sublimetext2 to play around in.  Is there more of a benefit to using jsFiddle?

Comment: I did, my reputation isn't high enough for it to register publicly.